# hash gvfs-backends results in "gvfs-backends : not found" (but it is installed)

Tags: bash

Like the title says, I've got gvfs-backends installed but if I check that in a bash script:

```
if ! hash nmap gvfs-backends 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "either nmap or gvfs-backends is not installed"
    exit
fi
```

the script exits when run.
In a terminal emulator, if I manually enter

```
hash gvfs-backends
```

I get the error message

> bash: hash: gvfs-backends: not found

What's going on here? Am I using hash when I should be using something else? If so, what should I use instead?